# How to loop to extract certain variables from NETCDF files?

Tags: python, loops

In my simple code I extract one variable named `bet` from the NETCDF file and then I write it out of the NETCDF file as here:

```
import os, glob 
print(filenamels)
for fn in filenamels:
outputFile = fn[:len(fn)-3]+'_ull_st.dat'
os.system( gdalcmd)
```

There are other variables `feg,dis,lam`, named ,in these NETCDF files and I do not want to run the code for each variable.I wonder how we can write a loop to extract these variables at once.

Answer (score 1):

`ncks` from the NCO package (http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html) is the way to go here.  For example, extracting variables `bet, feg, dis, lam` from a file called `myfile.nc` and outputting them into a file called `myfileout.nc` would be:

```
ncks -v bet,feg,dis,lam myfile.nc -O myfileout.nc
```

Comment: You can extract data from the netcdf file and store it in a `.dat` file with `ncks -v bet -s '%f\n' file.nc > output.dat`.